# Is there a reason for sacrificing a ram of a certain color and color around the eyes?

Tags: hadith-interpretation, animals, eid-ul-adha, sacrifice

Going through hadiths where Muhammad SAW sacrificed an animal, I noticed that there is a similar description or pattern about the type of animal he SAW used to sacrifice.

My question is: is there a reason for choosing a ram of a certain color and color around the eyes?

Below are some hadith related to the description of the animal:

> Sunan Ibn Majah » Chapters on Sacrifices  “The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ)
>   sacrificed a horned, defectless ram with a black stomach, black feet
>   and black around its eyes.”  English reference     : Vol. 4, Book 26,
>   Hadith 3128 Arabic reference   : Book 26, Hadith 3248
>
> Sunan Abi Dawud » Book of Sacrifice (Kitab Al-Dahaya)  The Messenger
>   of Allah (ﷺ) used to sacrifice a choice, horned ram with black round
>   the eyes, the mouth and the feet.  English translation     : Book 15,
>   Hadith 2790
>
> Jami` at-Tirmidhi » The Book on Sacrifices » Hadith "The Messenger of
>   Allah (ﷺ) slaughtered a horned male ram of fine pedigree, (around) his
>   mouth was black, and his legs were black, and (around) his eyes was
>   black. English translation     : Vol. 3, Book 17, Hadith 1496
>
> Sunan Abi Dawud » Book of Sacrifice (Kitab Al-Dahaya) The Prophet
>   (Saws) ordered a horned ram with black legs, black belly and black
>   round the eyes, and it was brought from him to sacrifice. He said:
>   'Aishah, get the knife then he said: Sharpen it with a stone. So I
>   did. He took it, then take the ram he placed it on the ground and
>   slaughtered it. He then said: In the name of Allah. O Allah, accept it
>   for Muhammad, Muhammad's family and Muhammad's people. Then he
>   sacrificed it. English translation     : Book 15, Hadith 2786

Comment: Off topic: In Morocco, people call these for "sundri", in the eid these are always more expensive than "normal" animals.

Comment: I don't understand your comment, and why do you say its off-topic?